# Swift, why Struct's static property cannot be used in "computed property" but can be used in "stored property"

Tags: ios, swift, struct, static

The code snippet shows 4 different ways to access a `static property` of a `struct`. Interesting enough that only the 4th one gets the error: `"Static member 'size' cannot be used on instance of type 'Learn_W'"` Could you help explain why the other three can access the `static property` of the `struct` without using `Self.` as prefix, but only the `test4` has to add the `Self.`as prefix to access the static property `size` ?

```
struct Learn_W: View {
    
    private static let size: CGFloat = 50
    
    
    let test1 = size
    
    var test2 = size
    
    struct test3 {
        let a = size
        var b = size
    }

    var test4: CGFloat {
        get {return size}
    } // "Static member 'size' cannot be used on instance of type 'Learn_W'"
```

My speculation: the difference is whether the static property is accessed in “Computed property” or “Stored property”. I guess that it’s related to the initialization process of a struct. For stored property, it’s always initialized before an instance is available, so the initialization process would automatically refer the internal “self” as the struct type itself. But “computed property” is not initialized when the instance is available, and it’s evaluated only (not 100% sure, it’s just my speculation) when it’s called in the form `instance.computed_property`, therefore, it’s being accessed directly though an instance, and in that context the “self” automatically refers to the instance but not type

Answer (score 1):

In all 4 cases, you reference to `size` is shorthand for `self.size`.

For each call originating from a static context (the first 3), `self` is referring to the `Learn_W` type itself, which has a `size`, so it works.

In the last case, the call is happening from an instanced context, where `self` refers to an instance of `Learn_W` (not `Learn_W`). Since instances of `Learn_W` don’t have a size, the lookup is invalid.

Comment: Yes, would you explain why only in the case test4, `self` refers to an instance, while the previous 3 cases automatically refer to the type itself?

Comment: @Jason that’s just how instance functions (methods), properties, etc. work. An method wouldn’t make sense without access to an instance to operate on. Think about it this way: what other way could it be?

Comment: I put some of my speculation below my question, I guess it might be related to the initialization process and the difference between stored property and computed property.

Comment: @Jason I'll address it piecemeal. "For stored property, it’s always initialized before an instance is available" To clarify: an instance exists (obviously, otherwise where would these properties be that you're initializing?), but the language doesn't allow you access it. This is to prevent property initializers referencing each other in a potentially cyclical way. There are other ways to have made that work (e.g. in Java they can only access properties declared up, so reading bottom-to-top gives you a DAG of dependencies), but in Swift they opted to disallow it entirely